# Sub-Module child routes not working ("Error: Cannot match any routes.")

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using Angular 6.0.3. I have a sub-module called "Admin" with three components. Admin's root component ("AdminComponent") route works fine (`path: ""`), but I can't seem to trigger any of the others. Why can't Angular find my routes?

routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { SplashComponent } from "./splash/splash.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { WatchComponent } from "./watch/watch.component";

import { AdminComponent } from "./admin/admin/admin.component";
import { HomeComponent as AdminHomeComponent } from "./admin/home/home.component";
import { AddSongComponent } from "./admin/add-song/add-song.component";
import { AdminGuard } from "./auth/admin.guard";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      { path: "", component: SplashComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "watch", component: WatchComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminComponent,
        pathMatch: "full",
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: "",
            component: AdminHomeComponent,
            pathMatch: "full",
            outlet: "admin"
          },
          {
            path: "add-song",
            component: AddSongComponent,
            pathMatch: "full",
            outlet: "admin"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

admin/admin/admin.component.html

`<router-outlet name='admin'></router-outlet>`

admin/home/home.component.html

```
<div>

   <a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['add-song']">Add new song</a>

</div>
```

note: I've also tried `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { admin: ['add-song'] } }]`, still route not found.

Comment: Hello there,

there might be a problem with your named **router-outlet**. Can you provide a working stackblitz example? That way i could help you.

Comment: did the answer help you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at **[`Lazy-loading`](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)** feature while loading sub modules, which is the correct way to load when you have many modules.

In your case you have admin module as a sub module, so here is the routing Configuration,

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'splash', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'splash', component: SplashComponent },
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
    ], { enableTracing: true })]
```

and the Admin.module routing is as follows,

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '', component: AdminComponent,
        children: [

          { path: '', component: AdminHomeComponent }
          ,
          { path: 'add-song', component:  AddSongComponent}]
      }
  ])
  ]
```

[WORKING STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-routes-angular-lazyloading?file=app/app.component.ts)

**ROUTES:**

**Splash**

- [`https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/splash`](https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/splash)

**Admin**

- [`https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/admin`](https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/admin)

**Admin-AddSong**

- [`https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/admin/add-song`](https://nested-routes-angular-lazyloading.stackblitz.io/admin/add-song)

Comment: I want to separate my admin and front section by urls.
For admin I want the like this: `http://localhost:4200/admin/dashboard`. Url is matched with routs but it prints error in console that `http://localhost:4200/admin/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to create Admin related components in its own module?
Then you can create a `admin-routing.module.ts`

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'add-song', component: AddSongComponent },
          { path: 'something-else', component: SomeOtherComponent },
          { path: '', component: AdminDefaultComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

Then in your main `app-routing.module` you can refer to it as

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SplashComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
  },
  { path: '**', component: SomeOtherComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**edit**: I noticed that you did create its own sub module, so you'll need to create a routing-module for this sub-module.

Answer (score 2):

This might be late reply, but i would like to focus on 1 important thing, angular compiler is very smart which detects on which root you currently on.So if you are calling any nested route from .html template it will automatically checks your current route in the url and what ever route you want this will simply append this to current route.

In simple terms, What you are trying to do in your code from `admin/home/home.component.html` you are trying to trigger `add-song` route and it will give you result as `admin/add-song` doesn't exist.This is pretty much expected though

sharing routes config. for children and some other code snippet.

```
children: [
      {
        path: "admin-home",
        component: AdminHomeComponent,
        pathMatch: "full",
        outlet: "admin"
      },
      {
        path: "add-song", 
        component: AddSongComponent, 
        pathMatch: "full",
        outlet: "admin"
      },
      {path: '', 
      redirectTo:'admin-home', 
      pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
```

now from your `admin/home/home.component.html` use below routerLink

```
  <div>
    <a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['/add-song']">Add new song</a>
  </div>
```

Untill now you were trying to add relative path, In angular specially in routerLink, it will detect current path and will append expected path to the end of your current path.so it will give you error.So try to provide absolute path in your nested routes.

But this.router.navigate() method won't understand it's current route automatically.It always starts route from root route.i.e if you are trying to call nested path from .ts file then angular won't recognize current path.So if you willing to tell angular that which is current route then from .ts file you can do something like this

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
...
this.router.navigate(['./add-song'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

One more thing is like `<a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['add-song']">Add new song</a>` this is as same as `<a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['./add-song']">Add new song</a>` Or `<a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['../add-song']">Add new song</a>` this is relative path, you must use absolute path

Otherwise try calling your route from .ts component without `relativeTo` property and relative path.

Hope this may work for you

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a working example of your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-routes-angular-lazyloading-dhup6q), the fix was simply removing `pathMatch: 'full'` everywhere except for the redirect route.

> A redirect route requires a pathMatch property to tell the router how to match a URL to the path of a route. The router throws an error if you don't. In this app, the router should select the route to the HeroListComponent only when the entire URL matches '', so set the pathMatch value to 'full'.

[Consider the docs, to learn more about the property.](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not defining any component for **path ""**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { SplashComponent } from "./splash/splash.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { WatchComponent } from "./watch/watch.component";

import { AdminComponent } from "./admin/admin/admin.component";
import { HomeComponent as AdminHomeComponent } from "./admin/home/home.component";
import { AddSongComponent } from "./admin/add-song/add-song.component";
import { AdminGuard } from "./auth/admin.guard";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SplashComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "watch", component: WatchComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminComponent,
        pathMatch: "full",
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: "",
            component: AdminHomeComponent,
            pathMatch: "full",
            outlet: "admin"
          },
          {
            path: "add-song",
            component: AddSongComponent,
            pathMatch: "full",
            outlet: "admin"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: I changed the top level to `component: SplashComponent` and now it can't find any other routes besides "".

Comment: According to your project, if admin / add-song is clicked, what will be desired path? @zakdances

Comment: It's supposed to load the AddSongComponent with the path "admin/add-song"

Comment: Okay, and one more query, what is your default component? When the path is ""?

Comment: The root component at "" is supposed to be SplashComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is related to the path which is angular generating for anchor tag. currently you are referring to a path "add-song". Angular considers this path as "localhost:4200/add-song". If you want to route it to admin/add-song then you need to define the full path (don't know why angular do this). If you could try

```
 <a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['admin/add-song']">Add new song</a>
```

This may work for the time but it would not be a perfect solution.
Thanks